# How to handle questions with upvoted answers that have been edited radically?

Tags: discussion, support

I have left a comment under [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15437012/please-remove-this) yesterday (while it was unedited). Meanwhile it has a few answers, one with two upvotes. The author has now removed most of the content of his question, and it basically only states "*Please remove this.*". Isn't the OP able to delete the question himself? If no, which of the following is more appropriate:

1. Edit the question, rolling it back to the first revision. This way the answers make sense and the users keep their gained reputation or
2. Flag the question for deletion, since it's a duplicate and (in it's current form) has very low quality.

I wasn't sure if the discussion or support tag was better for this kind of question. I am basically looking for a rule of thumb on how to handle this kind of situation in future cases.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe: Yes, that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do point 1. You rollback to the previous revision.

In most cases one, or more, of the following is also appropriate; it's up to you.

1. Edit the question into shape.
2. Vote to close
3. Vote to reopen
4. Vote to delete
5. Flag for moderator attention
6. Leave a comment for the OP asking them not to do this.

There cannot be a generic rule, sometimes the OP has a great question and just doesn't understand what they are doing. Sometimes, the question is so bad that insta-deletion becomes a useful tool. What actually happens to each question depends on the question itself, the people who interact with it and to a certain extent the behaviour of the OP. You should do what you think is right, no more, and leave it at that.

Don't forget to rollback first.